# Will onLocationChanged still get called even though it is not in the Service's onStart?

Tags: java, android, locationlistener

I have a Service that needs to get the user's location when they move.  I haven't been able to figure out how to put onLocationChanged inside onStart, so I just put it outside.  Will it still be called when the user moves?  If not, how would I call it in onStart?

```
public class myService extends Service implements LocationListener {
Double lat;
Double lng;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
// Let it continue running until it is stopped.
Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();





return START_STICKY;

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
super.onDestroy();
Toast.makeText(this, "Service Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}



@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

if (MainActivity.location != null) {


   lat = MainActivity.location.getLatitude();

    lng = MainActivity.location.getLongitude();


    if (MainActivity.placeArrayList.size() != 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < MainActivity.placeArrayList.size(); i++) {


            Log.e("hello", String.valueOf(Float.parseFloat(MainActivity.latitudeArrayList.get(i))));

            MainActivity.destination.setLatitude(Double.parseDouble(MainActivity.latitudeArrayList.get(i)));
            MainActivity.destination.setLongitude(Double.parseDouble(MainActivity.longitudeArrayList.get(i)));
            Log.e("distancemeters", String.valueOf(MainActivity.location.distanceTo(MainActivity.destination)));

            if (MainActivity.location.distanceTo(MainActivity.destination)<100) {




                AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

                audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);


            } else {



            }

        }


    }
}

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using Google's [FusedLocationProviderApi](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi.html), you need to do a couple of things first:

1. Change your class to implement `GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks` and `GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener`
2. Create your GoogleApi object
3. Create your LocationRequest object
4. Register your class as a LocationListener

First, change your class definition as follows:

```
public class myService extends Service implements LocationListener,      
                                                  GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, 
                                                  GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
```

Then put this in your `onStart()` method:

```
// 2. Create the GoogleApi object
GoogleApi = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();

// 3. Create the LocationRequest
mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000); // in milliseconds
mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000); // in milliseconds
mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

// 4. Register your listener
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(GoogleApi, mLocationRequest, this)
```

If you want to unregister your listener, put this in `onDestroy()`:

```
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(GoogleApi, this);
```

However, keep in mind that using this method means you will get a location update at specified time intervals, **not** when the user moves. You will need to find a way of keeping track of the user's location and determining a minimum distance which constitutes "movement". Also you will need to consider that the location might dance around the user's location so you will also have to take this into account.

Comment: One small thing, MainActivity.getAppContext() is unrecognized. It doesnt know what getAppContext() is

Comment: Sorry - I lifted the code from one of my projects. You just need to pass in a reference to your Service i.e. `this`. Edited my answer to reflect this.